# How to Conditionally the column in LINQ OrderByDescending for OrderBy?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, dynamic-linq

How to Conditionally sort the column using LINQ OrderBy Clause.

ex- I have a Property `Filter.OrderBy` and `Filter.Order`. In `OrderBy` could be many ex> Name, Address, City etc and `Order` will be ascending or descending but I am not sure how to sort it with conditional columns.

Please find the below code for reference:

```
IQueryable<Filter> query;

PropertyInfo prop = typeof(Filter).GetProperty(Filter.OrderBy);  

if (Filter.Order ==" Ascending"){
  query = query.OrderBy ( x = > prop.GetValue(x,null));
}
else if (Filter.Order ==" Descending"){
  query = query.OrderByDescending ( x = > prop.GetValue(x,null));
}
```

But query is failing. I am not sure what is the issue I can see the prop property using reflection
but the expression prop.GetValue is not working.

Please help me on this.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: @dcg query is not able to find sort by using query.OrderBy column it seems I am not able to change the property dynamically ex - x => x.Address etc

Comment: So `query.OrderBy(x => x.Address)` doesn't work?

Comment: @RoadRunner it works but i need to change the column dynamically like it could be x =>x.Address or x.City or x.State . So, I dont wan to hardcode or create multiple conditions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# use string parameter to define what property to filter by in List of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57607655/c-sharp-use-string-parameter-to-define-what-property-to-filter-by-in-list-of-obj) - although this is a `Where` clause, it should be easy to adapt to `OrderBy`

Comment: BTW you are comparing with `" Ascending"` and `" Descending"` (with leading space), is that right? Otherwise you'll never be composing the OrderBy query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the library [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) which supports dynamic querying, selecting and ordering.

Example code:

```
var q = new List<Person>
{
    new Person{Name = "C", Age = 30 },
    new Person{Name = "A", Age = 7 },
    new Person{Name = "B", Age = 5 }
}.AsQueryable();

var x1 = q.OrderBy("Name asc");

var a1 = q.OrderBy("Age desc");
```

For a full working example, see [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ihOmzz)

Comment: This solution worked for me and it is very easy to implement thanks @Stef Heyenrath

Answer (score 0):

I created this sample, maybe it can help you

```
IEnumerable<Person> q = new List<Person>
{
    new Person{Name = "C", Age = 3 },
    new Person{Name = "A", Age = 7 },
    new Person{Name = "B", Age = 5 }
};
var props = new[] { "Name", "Age" };
var orders = new[] { "Ascending", "Descending" };

foreach (var prop in props)
{
    var property = typeof(Person).GetProperty(prop);
    foreach (var order in orders)
    {
        IEnumerable<Person> q2 = null;
        if (order == "Ascending")
        { q2 = q.OrderBy(p => property.GetValue(p)); }
        else
        { q2 = q.OrderByDescending(p => property.GetValue(p)); }

        Console.WriteLine("Property: {0}, Order: {1}", prop, order);
        foreach (var p in q2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Age: {1}", p.Name, p.Age);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Property: Name, Order: Ascending
Name: A, Age: 7
Name: B, Age: 5
Name: C, Age: 3

Property: Name, Order: Descending
Name: C, Age: 3
Name: B, Age: 5
Name: A, Age: 7

Property: Age, Order: Ascending
Name: C, Age: 3
Name: B, Age: 5
Name: A, Age: 7

Property: Age, Order: Descending
Name: A, Age: 7
Name: B, Age: 5
Name: C, Age: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

set the properties as params.
Example:

```
var param = "Address";    
var propertyInfo = typeof(Filter).GetProperty(param);    
var orderByAddress = items.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class LinqUtils
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Orders the by.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
        /// <param name="direction">The direction.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IOrderedMongoQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IMongoQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, OrderDirection direction)
        {
            switch (direction)
            {
                case OrderDirection.ASC:
                    return source.OrderBy(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));

                case OrderDirection.DESC:
                    return source.OrderByDescending(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));

                default:
                    return source.OrderBy(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Orders the by.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
        /// <param name="direction">The direction.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IOrderedMongoQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IMongoQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, int direction)
        {
            var dir = (OrderDirection)direction;

            switch (dir)
            {
                case OrderDirection.ASC:
                    return source.OrderBy(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));

                case OrderDirection.DESC:
                    return source.OrderByDescending(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));

                default:
                    return source.OrderBy(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));
            }

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Orders the by.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IOrderedMongoQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IMongoQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
        {
            return source.OrderBy(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Orders the by descending.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IOrderedMongoQueryable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(this IMongoQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
        {
            return source.OrderByDescending(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Wheres the specified property name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
        /// <param name="stringToSource">The string to source.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IMongoQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IMongoQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string stringToSource)
        {
            return source.Where(ToLambdaWhere<T>(propertyName, stringToSource));
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Wheres the text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="query">The query.</param>
        /// <param name="field">The field.</param>
        /// <param name="search">The search.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IMongoQueryable<T> WhereText<T>(this IMongoQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, object>> field, string search)
        {

            search = Regex.Escape(search);
            var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Text(search);
            var member = HelpersLinq.PropertyName<T>(field);

            var regexFilter = string.Format("^{0}.*", search);
            var filterRegex = Builders<T>.Filter.Regex(member, BsonRegularExpression.Create(new Regex(regexFilter, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)));

            return query.Where(_ => filter.Inject() && filterRegex.Inject());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts to lambda.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
            var propAsObject = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(propAsObject, parameter);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts to lambdawhere.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
        /// <param name="stringToSearch">The string to search.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToLambdaWhere<T>(string propertyName, string stringToSearch)
        {
            //var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

            // Create a parameter to use for both of the expression bodies.
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            // Invoke each expression with the new parameter, and combine the expression bodies with OR.
            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Call(Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName), "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(stringToSearch)), parameter);

            return predicate;
        }
    }


    public static class HelpersLinq
    {
        public static string PropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
        {
            var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (member != null && member.Member is PropertyInfo)
                return member.Member.Name;

            throw new ArgumentException("Expression is not a Property", "expression");
        }
    }

public enum OrderDirection
{
    ASC = 1,
    DESC
}
```

So you can use it like :

```
 initialQuery.OrderBy("Name", OrderDirection.ASC)
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

download the `Linq.Dynamic` from nuget

add using ex:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic
```

use this code

```
query = query.OrderBy(Colum name + " " + ASC OR DESC);
```