# Is there a way to set a where clause in Entity Framework to a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this EF qQuery

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetCISCustomers(string Option, string Input)
{
    using (var db = new cismodel.eedcbuildingdbContext())
    {
        var result = from a in db.ConsolidatedCustomerDatabase
                     where (a.AccountNo == Input)
                     select new
                            {
                                AccountNo = a.AccountNo
                            };

        string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

        return Ok(json);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make the `a.AccountNo` to be the (Option) parameter as I want users to be able to pass in different options such as (AccountNo, MeterNo, Name) and different input.

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, `where (a.AccountNo == Input) || (a.AccountNo == Option)`?

Comment: So you want the user to be able to specify, using a string, on which column your query will query?

Comment: That's a little bit dangerous. You'd have to at least make sure the option exists. So, I'd probably use an Enum , split the query and add the where clause depending on the enum value. Remains the problem in the selector. You'd need to return the respective result, too.

Comment: I get this i do not know what the user will like to do the where on. The user could use where(a.AccountNo == input) where (a.Meterno == Input). I want it to be something like where(a.Option == input)

Comment: @Fildor Yes that is what i want. I can ensure the options exist. Can you write the query structure to your suggestion?

Comment: @CodeCaster Exactly!

Comment: I amended my prior comment. One thing I did not take into account: When I did this, I always returned the same result type. I used it just as a filter. But here this would also affect the result.

Comment: Well, not really like this. using `var` for `result` hides that it actually has a type. That is an anonymous type, which holds an `AccountNo`. That type is not dynamic, i.e. it has to be fixed at compile time. So this way you cannot simply switch it to be an anonymous type that holds a `Meterno` or so.

Comment: Please see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57607655/592958) which shows how to create a dynamic expression that takes a string value to create a filter. It's a little more complicated but is completely generic and won't require maintenance when properties are added or removed from your model and could be modified to act on any class.

Answer (score 1):

You can write base query as `IQueryable` and have filtering based on your condition :

```
 IQueryable<EntityName> query = db.ConsolidatedCustomerDatabase;

 if(option == "A")
 {
      query = query.Where(x=>x.A == Input);
 }
 else if (option == "B")
 {
      query = query.Where(x=>x.B == Input);
 }
```

When you are done with adding filtering, you can materialize the query:

```
 var result = query.Select(x => new { AccountNo = x.AccountNo }).ToList();
```

Comment: It's the general idea like this that'll work (if you declare `query` as `IQueryable<ActualEntity>`), but stuff like this quickly turns into a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: OP will still have to alter the select, too. If I query for `MeterNo`, I don't want `AccountNo` as the result.

Comment: @Fildor I don't see that in the OP's request. They want to filter the same collection on different properties, but might just want to return all properties.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ah, you may be right. I somehow inferred that.

Comment: @CodeCaster : I agree with you on maintenance point but IQueryable come in handy when you've to write conditional filtering.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Fixed, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an Expression as a method parameter, e.g.

```cs
AccountNoType GetAccountNoForSelector(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> selector)
{
    return db.ConsolidatedCustomerDatabase
        .Where(selector)
        .Select(c => c.AccountNo)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Then call it like

```cs
var myAccount = GetAccountNoForSelector(c => c.MeterNo == 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the possible values of `Option`, then you can build a conditional logic like below.

```
    var result = from a in db.ConsolidatedCustomerDatabase
                 where (Option == "AccountNo" && a.AccountNo == Input) 
                        || (Option == "MeterNo" && a.MeterNo == Input)
                 select new
                 {
                     AccountNo = a.AccountNo
                 };
```

Comment: Is it possible not to hard code the Option = "AccountNo", Option = "AccountNo" and make it open. I will prefer to pass it from the web api get endpoint

Comment: I will like my web api to be called as 

localhost:2067/api/Incidence/GetCISCustomers?Option=AccountNo&&Input=0003403108

localhost:2067/api/Incidence/GetCISCustomers?Option=MeterNo&&Input=0003403108

Comment: I have not build that but it seems it's possible by using reflection. [link](https://michael-mckenna.com/sorting-iqueryables-using-strings-and-reflection/) Anyway, i would not prefer to use it that way. I will go with either building conditional logic or create multiple routes for options.

Comment: Ok. Creating multiple routes for options is pretty easy i just wanted to see the possibility of having just one dynamic route

Comment: Yep, i think it also will be a cleaner approach.