# Entity Framework C# queries from strings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, linq

Is it possible to get elements in a sqlite table from a string with the name of the table (using Entity Framework)? How?

And how can I get only the value of a property? (I need to get a list of IDs to create a  in html that's used to choose which element in a table the user wants to delete)

```
using using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public static List<string> GetAllIdsFromTableName(string tableName)
    {
        var db = new dbContext();

        // What I would like to do: 
        // return db.tableName.Select(x => x.id).ToList<string>();
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just map your table?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But give more details. What is your table structure? Basically, expression which you wrote could be valid, if your table has entities which have id.

Comment: @kosist all my entities have an id which is also the primary key and it's always the fist field in the table. i need to do this so i can call a generic function which returns all the ids to create a <select> in the html page

Comment: `var ids = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>($"Select id from {table}").ToList();` ?

Comment: returns this error: "CS1061: 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'SqlQuery' and no accessible extension method 'SqlQuery' accepting a first argument of
type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: How to properly execute raw SQL is described in detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).  Worth noting: I don't think you can parameterize the table name like that.

Comment: So I have to use a long long switch case?

Comment: It's unlikely that you will need this capability for every table.  Using every ID in a given table, you should be favoring joins, not collections of IDs.

Comment: i only need the ids of one table. example: table "Users" -> list of all users IDs

Comment: i think i'll have to do it with a huge switch case or in javascript in the front end

Comment: Why though?  What purpose could having all of the ids in a table possibly serve?

Comment: i need it to create a <select> in html that's used to choose which element in a table the user wants to delete

Comment: @JuriMason You could do this with reflection to target the appropriate "table" and create a dynamic expression to query the table on a property named `id`. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57608386/592958) for information regarding building a dynamic expression.

Comment: @phuzi could you please show me an example? I've never used reflection or dynamic expressions before

Comment: Using ajax to request the backend controller, the controller deletes a row of data from the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following extension returns `IQueryable<string>` and you can materialise  arrays, lists, or you can do it asynchronously:

```cs
var result = context.GetAllIdsFromTable("SomeTable", "Id")
    .ToList();
```

And implementation:

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo _toStringMethod = typeof(Convert).GetMethods()
        .Single(m =>
            m.Name == nameof(Convert.ToString) && m.GetParameters().Length == 1 &&
            m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(object)
        );

    public static IQueryable<string> GetAllIdsFromTable(this DbContext ctx, string tableName, string idColumnName = "Id")
    {
        var model = ctx.Model;

        var entityType = model.GetEntityTypes().FirstOrDefault(et =>
            tableName.Equals(et.GetTableName(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (entityType == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Entity for table '{tableName}' not found.");

        // GetColumnName() can be obsolete, it depends on EF Core version.
        var prop = entityType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p =>
            idColumnName.Equals(p.GetColumnName(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (prop == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Property for column '{tableName}'.'{idColumnName}' not found.");

        var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");
        var ctxParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DbContext), "ctx");

        // ctx.Set<entityType>()
        var setQuery = Expression.Call(ctxParam, nameof(DbContext.Set), new[] { entityType.ClrType });

        Expression propExpression;
        if (prop.PropertyInfo == null)
            // 'prop' is Shadow property, so call via EF.Property(e, "name")
            propExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Property), new[] { prop.ClrType },
                entityParam, Expression.Constant(prop.Name));
        else
            propExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(entityParam, prop.PropertyInfo);

        propExpression = EnsureString(propExpression);

        // e => e.Prop
        var propLambda = Expression.Lambda(propExpression, entityParam);

        // ctx.Set<entityType>().Select(e => e.Prop)
        Expression selectAll = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Select),
            new[] { entityType.ClrType, typeof(string) },
            setQuery, Expression.Quote(propLambda));

        var constructQuery = Expression.Lambda<Func<DbContext, IQueryable<string>>>(selectAll, ctxParam);

        return constructQuery.Compile()(ctx);
    }

    private static Expression EnsureString(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression.Type == typeof(string))
            return expression;

        if (expression.Type != typeof(object))
            expression = Expression.Convert(expression, typeof(object));

        expression = Expression.Call(_toStringMethod, expression);

        return expression;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. this is great! i just need to adapt it a bit to my code but it already works fine

Comment: could i use it also to remove elements some way?

Comment: For removing it is need another code. Better to create new question with more details.

Comment: Here's the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73119924/entity-framework-c-sharp-queries-from-string-parameters