# How to avoid duplicate code in linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, expressionbuilder

I have the code which can be considered as repetetive:

```
private IEnumerable<decimal?> GetWidth(IEnumerable<Rectangle> rectangles) =>
    rectangles.Where(s => s.Width != null)
    .Select(s => s.Width);

private IEnumerable<decimal?> GetHeight(IEnumerable<Rectangle> rectangles) =>
    rectangles.Where(s => s.Height != null)
        .Select(s => s.Height);

private IEnumerable<decimal?> GetDiameter(IEnumerable<Rectangle> rectangles) =>
    rectangles.Where(s => s.Diameter != null)
    .Select(s => s.Diameter);

private IEnumerable<decimal?> GetWeight(IEnumerable<Rectangle> rectangles) =>
    rectangles.Where(s => s.Weight != null)
        .Select(s => s.Weight);
```

The only difference between these methods is just field names such as `Width, Height, Diameter, Weight`.    Is it possible to replace these names with a string property name and create just one method without using any third party libraries?

Comment: Do you really want to replace these 4 calls to a single call which gets all the widths, heights diameters and weights of all rectangles?

Comment: You can remove one expression if you reverse `Where()` and `Select()`, eg `items.Select(s =>s.Height).Where(x=>x!=null);`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create simple extension for that:

```cs
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TValue> ExtractValues<TEntity, TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<TEntity> items,
        Func<TEntity, TValue?>    selector)
    {
        return items.Where(i => selector(i) != null)
            .Select(i => selector(i)!);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```cs
var heights   = items.ExtractValues(i => i.Height);
var diameters = items.ExtractValues(i => i.Diameter);
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you use IEnumerable and the arguments simply select and check value, you can *reverse* the operations to select the value and filter out nulls. You're still performing the same simple operations - checking all values but allowing only the non-null ones:

```
var heights=items.Select(s =>s.Height).Where(x=>x!=null);
var diameters=items.Select(s =>s.Diameter).Where(x=>x!=null);
var weights=items.Select(s =>s.Weight).Where(x=>x!=null);
```

You can convert that to an expression method :

```
IEnumerable<TResult> SelectNonNull<TSource,TResult>( 
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource,TResult?> selector) 
{
    return source.Select(selector).Where(x=>x!=null);
}

...
var heights=items.SelectNotNull(s =>s.Height);
var diameters=items.SelectNotNull(s =>s.Diameter);
var weights=items.SelectNotNull(s =>s.Weight);
```

Answer (score 3):

In this specific example I would introduce a separate method to do the null check. Something like :

```
public static T NotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> list) where T : struct 
    => list.Where(t => t.HasValue).Select( t => t.Value);

private IEnumerable<decimal> GetWeight(IEnumerable<Rectangle> rectangles) =>
    rectangles.Select(s => s.Weight).NotNull();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use a string to indicate which property to get you can build up a dynamic select as an extension method.

Also, by switching around `Where().Select()` to `Select().Where()` allows you to only need a single dynamic expression too. i.e.

```cs
rectangles
    .Where(s => s.Width != null)
    .Select(s => s.Width);

// becomes

rectangles
    .Select(s => s.Width)
    .Where(s => s != null);
```

Right, so how do you build the dynamic filter?

You could do something like this - based on [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57607655/c-sharp-use-string-parameter-to-define-what-property-to-filter-by-in-list-of-obj/57608386#57608386)

```cs
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<decimal?> GetProperty(
        this IEnumerable<Rectangle> rectangles,
        string property)
    {
        var queryableRectangles = rectangles.AsQueryable();
        
        // w =>
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Rectangle), "w");
    
        var propertyInfo = typeof(Rectangle).GetProperty(property);
        if (propertyInfo == null)
            throw new Exception($@"Property ""{property}"" was not found");
    
        // w.[property]
        var selector = Expression.Property(param, propertyInfo);
    
        // Bring it all together
        // Select(w => w.[property])
        var selectExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            nameof(System.Linq.Enumerable.Select),
            new Type[] { typeof(Rectangle), typeof(decimal?) },
            queryableRectangles.Expression,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<Rectangle, decimal?>>(selector, new ParameterExpression[] { param })
        );
    
        // Query the collection
        var filteredItems = queryableRectangles.Provider.CreateQuery<decimal?>(selectExpression);
    
        // return the list of values removing null values.
        return filteredItems
            .Where(x => x.HasValue) // Use HasValue instead of != null for Nullable<t>
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

You could then use this in your code

```cs
var heights = rectangles.GetProperty("Height");
```

### UPDATE - Completely generic version

To make this completely generic is fairly easy to replace `Rectangle with` T`and`decimal?`with TOut, of course you need to update the method signature a little with the generic type parameters to`<T, TOut>`

**Note the change from `.Where(x => x.HasValue)` back to `.Where(x => x != null)**

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TOut> GetProperty<T, TOut>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string property)
{
    var queryable = source.AsQueryable();

    // w =>
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "w");

    var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(property);
    if (propertyInfo == null)
        throw new Exception($@"Property ""{property}"" was not found");

    // w.[property]
    var selector = Expression.Property(param, propertyInfo);

    // Bring it all together
    // Select(w => w.[property])
    var selectExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        nameof(System.Linq.Enumerable.Select),
        new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(TOut) },
        queryable.Expression,
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TOut>>(selector, new ParameterExpression[] { param })
    );

    // Run query against the database
    var filteredItems = queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<TOut>(selectExpression);

    return filteredItems
        .Where(x => x != null) // revert to != null for non Nullable<T> return types
        .ToList();
}
```

This requires a slight tweak to the way it's called too:

```cs
var heights = rectangles.GetProperty<Rectangle, decimal?>("Height");
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! Upvoted! I am just wondering if it is possible to make it generic, not just for `Rectangle`?

Comment: Yep, see my updated answer. Generics aren't that difficult once you get your head round them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. I upvoted your  different answers. I am sorry for my lack of understanding, but could you help me to write not with string, but like this selector? The code would look like this: `GetProperty<Rectangle, decimal?>(s => s.Height);`

Comment: If you're providing the expression then building the expression dynamically is overkill for your needs and I would probably go with the answer from [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76587590/592958).

Comment: thank for your response. if it is possible, could you show please how it can be done.

Comment: There's not much point! All this code does is dynamically creates the `s => s.Weight` expression and execute it against the collection. If you already have the expression then the method collapses down to `source.Select(selector).Where(x => x != null)` which is the same as Panagiotis's answer.